# Rollback code in neatbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, github

I'm working on a java project in neatbeans 7.3 and github. The problem is this:I was writing code when (without make commit or push)I've made a pull from github and my code was deleted. Is there a technicque to rollback to previous code?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans keeps a local history of file edits. If the edits were recent then you should be able to use that to roll back the changes you have made.

Just go to `Team -> Local History -> Show Local History` and then you can look at what Netbeans has stored.